# How to extract Regression predictor of Scikit-learn to implement into C++?

Tags: python, c++, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I did some training using Random Forest Regression (or any kind of regressions) of Scikit-learn and got the predictor:

```
predictor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=n_estimators)
predictor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

How can I extract information in `predictor` to implement into C++ as a filter only for prediction?

What I need is to build a "predictor" in C++ to get: `Y_predict = predictor(X_test)` without any training in C++.

Comment: It's unclear what you're really asking here -- Are you asking for how you might be able to implement random forest in C++?  Because that might be too large a question for the format here ...

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to put your content quality up

Comment: @ mgilson: thank you, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The [sklearn documentation for RFR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) says that you have

```
 property estimators_ : list of DecisionTreeRegressor
```

From [DecisionTreeRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) you can get the attributes you need, specifically tree_ attribute.